# View Manager Error during going back React Native Vision Camera

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-camera, react-native-reanimated-v2, react-native-vision-camera

When users clicks a button, i am navigating user to new screen. In the new screen a camera opens by using react native vision camera. But when i am pressing back buttons "View Manager for tag" error is showing instead going back to previous screen.

```
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);

  const [barcodes, setBc] = useState([]);
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(true);

  const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.back;

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function scanBarcodes(frame, types, options) {
    'worklet';
    return __scanCodes(frame, types, options);
  }

  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
    'worklet';
    const detectedBarcodes = scanBarcodes(frame, [BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE], { checkInverted: true });
    runOnJS(setBc)(detectedBarcodes);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let granted = await Permission.checkPermission(PERMISSION_TYPE.camera);
      if (!granted) {
        granted = await Permission.requestPermission(PERMISSION_TYPE.camera);
      }
      setHasPermission(granted);
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', () => {
      setHasPermission(false);
      setBc([]);
      setActive(false);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  const onSuccess = (e) => {};

  if (device != null && hasPermission) {
    return (
      <>
        <Camera
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          device={device}
          isActive={isActive}
          frameProcessor={frameProcessor}
          frameProcessorFps={5}
        />
        {barcodes.map((barcode, idx) => (
          <Text key={idx} style={styles.barcodeTextURL}>
            {barcode.displayValue}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Need Permission</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

[image: Error]

Any suggestion why this is happening?

Using -
"react-native-reanimated": "2.3.0-alpha.3",
"react-native-vision-camera": "2.13.0",
"vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"

Comment: Hey this may be due to frameProcessor . Please try it with : frameProcessor={frameProcessor ? frameProcessor : undefined}

Comment: Still same error...